# How to add a character to the back of a char array when you obtain it with a gets() function in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have an array of charracters where I put in information using a gets().

```
char inname[30];
gets(inname);
```

How can I add another character to this array without knowing the length of the string in c? (the part that are actual letters and not like empty memmory spaces of romething)

note: my buffer is long enough for what I want to ask the user (a filename, Probebly not many people have names longer that 29 characters)

Comment: Length of the previous string must be determined by any means if you want to append another characters to it.

Comment: [**Never use `gets()`**!!](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: allright how do i detirmine it (like when does the string reaches /0 or \0 or whatever it is to end of a string)

Comment: `strcat` might be useful here (though, in essence, this function **does** search for the end of the string before concatenating another string to it).

Comment: @CoolGuy why, what to use instead

Comment: If you use scanf() instead of gets() you will get the number of characters entered in return value,you can use them.

Comment: [Just to complete what Mr. @CoolGuy said]... use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: but I want the string to be inputted(if that's a word) by the user

Comment: @SouravGhosh 'fgets()'  is for files,right

Comment: 1. `for (i=0; inname[i]!=0; i++) {}`. 2. `inname[i] = your_char;`. 3. `inname[i+1] = 0;`.

Comment: @CoderGuy yes, you can make use of `stdin` in your case.

Comment: @CoderGuy use `stdin` for the `FILE*`

Comment: @WhozCraig so this means I use a char array instead of a file? how nifty

Comment: `gets(array)` -> `fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin)` as you see you pass the array size and hence prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: @CoderGuy , No. What WhozCraig said is to use the third argument(which you use for a `FILE` pointer) as `stdin`. The first argument is a `char*`

Comment: @CoderGuy you can't add a character without knowing the length of the string in c.

Comment: well I can count the characters and overwrite the `\0` with another character and the empty space afterward with `\0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `gets` is prone to buffer overflow and should be avoided.

Reading a line of input:

```
char inname[30];
sscanf("%.*s", sizeof(inname), inname);
int len = strlen(inname);
// Remove trailing newline
if (len > 0 && inname[len-1] == '\n') {
    len--;
    inname[len] = '\0'
}
```

Appending to the string:

```
char *string_to_append = ".";
if (len + strlen(string_to_append) + 1) <= sizeof(inname)) {
    // There is enough room to append the string
   strcat(inname, string_to_append); 
}
```

Optional way to append a single character to the string:

```
if (len < sizeof(inname) - 2) {
    // There is room to add another character
   inname[len++] = '.'; // Add a '.' character to the string.
   inname[len] = '\0';  // Don't forget to nul-terminate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have asked in comment, to determine the string length you can directly use

```
strlen(inname);
```

OR

you can loop through string in a for loop until `\0` is found.

Now after getting the length of prvious string you can append new string as

```
strcat(&inname[prevLength],"NEW STRING");
```

EDIT:

To find the Null Char you can write a for loop like this

```
for(int i =0;inname[i] != 0;i++)
{
      //do nothing
}
```

Now you can use `i` direcly to copy any character at the end of string like:

```
inname[i] = Youe Char;
```

After this increment i and again copy Null char to(0) it.

P.S.

Any String in C end with a Null character termination. ASCII null char `'\0`' is equivalent to `0` in decimal.

Comment: how can i test for the `\0` character

Comment: "To find the Null Char" ... simply use `i = strlen(inname)+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the final character of a C string is '\0', e.g. the array:

```
char foo[10]={"Hello"};
```

is equivalent to this array:

```
['H'] ['e'] ['l'] ['l'] ['0'] ['\0']
```

Thus you can iterate on the array until you find the '\0' character, and then you can substitute it with the character you want.
Alternatively you can use the function strcat of string.h library

Comment: how can i test for the `\0` character

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't.

In c you must know the length of the string to append `char`'s to it, in other languages the same applies but it happens magically, and without a doubt, internally the same must be done.

c strings are defined as sequences of bytes terminated by a special byte, the `nul` character which has ascii code `0` and is represented by the character `'\0'` in c.

You must find this value to append characters before it, and then move it after the appended character, to illustrate this suppose you have

```
char hello[10] = "Hello";
```

then you want to append a `'!'` after the `'o'` so you can just do this

```
size_t length;

length = strlen(hello);
/* move the '\0' one position after it's current position */
hello[length + 1] = hello[length]; 
hello[length]     = '!';
```

now the string is `"Hello!"`.

Of course, you should take car of `hello` being large enough to hold one extra character, that is also not automatic in c, which is one of the things I love about working with it because it gives you maximum flexibility.

You can of course use some available functions to achieve this without worrying about moving the `'\0'` for example, with

```
strcat(hello, "!");
```

you will achieve the same.

Both `strlen()` and `strcat()` are defined in `string.h` header.